# Jenkins when not allOf doesn't seem to work

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

there is a pipeline in my hand, what I'm trying to do is creating a conditional pipeline to build certain directories according to certain changesets. It's working, but also, I should be triggering all the deployments when the change is done in directory or files other than `*apps/**` and `*packages/**` paths. Also empty changeset should not trigger other deployments too. Despite the needs, when I run my pipeline for empty changeset, all my other deployments are being triggered for empty changeset with the code below. I guess my `when { not { allOf { }}}` block is not working. Because my conditional is not skipped even for empty changeset. Isn't it supposed to work or am I missing something.

```
stage('Get Change Size') {
    steps {
       script {
          changeCount = currentBuild.changeSets.size()
          echo "There are " + changeCount +  "changed files"
                }
            }       
        }
stage('Root Directory Change Condition') {
    when { 
       not {
         allOf {
            changeset "*apps/**" 
            changeset "*packages/**"
            expression { changeCount == 0 }
        }
    }
}
        steps {
           script {  
              deployAll=true
              echo "Value is" + deployAll + "for deployAll parameter"
                }
            }
        }
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your current condition is wrong and is not set to achieve what you want.
Think of it like this, if `changeCount == 0` then for sure `changeset "*apps/**"` is **false** as there are no changes, and therefore the `allOf` directive is **false**, the `not` will convert the final condition to **true** and the step will be execute although you didn't want it to.

To fix it the condition should be changed to the exact logic you want:
Run the stage only if there are changes that are not in `*apps/**` or there are changes not in `*packages/**` and also changeCount should be greater then 0.
Something like:

```groovy
stage('Root Directory Change Condition') {
    when { 
       allOf {      // This is actually the default behavior and can be omitted 
          anyOf {   // Use negative lookahead regex pattern to create a changeset filter that excludes certain paths
             changeset pattern: '^(?!.*apps\/).*', comparator: "REGEXP"  // There are changes which are not in the apps/* path
             changeset pattern: '^(?!.*packages\/).*', comparator: "REGEXP"  // There are changes which are not in the packages/* path
          }
          expression { changeCount > 0 } // Make sure there are any changes
        }
    }
    ... // stage code
}
```

This condition actually means: There must be any number of changes, and in addition the changes must be elsewhere then `*apps/**` or `*packages/**` folders - which is the exact condition you want.